# Accesing objects in multidimensional array, Obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, multidimensional-array

I have an array holding other arrays, but cant get this to work!! IM trying to pull  string values from subArrays I can access first the first subarray no problem but then when i try changing the label to the object in second array my prog crashes anyidea on how i should approach this?

```
int count = 0; // variable to access the required sub array 
NSArray* myArray; // array holding other arrays 
UILabel* mylabel; // label to display my string values from the array s

-(void) setLabel 
{

    NSArray* subArray = [myArray objectAtIndex: count];
    [myLabel setText:[subArray objectAtIndex:1]]; // this works fine
}

-(void) changeLabelToNextArray
{
    count ++
    [self setLabel]; //program crashes here when try to load label from next array 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this?

```
[myLabel setText:[subArray objectAtIndex:1]];
```

This will crash if

1. subArray does not have an object at index 1
2. the object at index 1 cannot be set as the label text (i.e cannot be made a string)

I think some more information on how your arrays are structured would help give a better answer to what the problem is.

EDIT (Based on comments below)
Try this:

```
NSArray* myArray;   // Contains 5 subarrays, each containing 5 strings

UILabel* myLabel1;
UILabel* myLabel2;
UILabel* myLabel3;
UILabel* myLabel4;
UILabel* myLabel5;

int count = 0;      // Keeps track of which subarray we are on

- (void)setLabel
{
    NSArray* subArray = [myArray objectAtIndex:count];
    [myLabel1 setText: [subArray objectAtIndex:0]]
    [myLabel2 setText: [subArray objectAtIndex:1]]
    [myLabel3 setText: [subArray objectAtIndex:2]]
    [myLabel4 setText: [subArray objectAtIndex:3]]
    [myLabel5 setText: [subArray objectAtIndex:4]]
    count = (count + 1) % 5;    // Ensures that count is always 0 to 4
}
```

Now whenever you call setLabel, the text should change on all 5 of your labels provided you do indeed have 5 strings in each of the 5 subarrays.

Comment: hey feanor, i have an array with 5 subarrays each subarray has  5 strings which im trying to display

Comment: So you have 25 strings in total and you want your method to change the text displayed by the UILabel one at a time?

Comment: kinda, i will have 5labels and hope to display the 5 strings from the first subarray then change the 5labels to display the 5strings from the second subarray

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer. Whenever you want the label text to change, call the setLabel method. It should work provided you do indeed have 5 strings in each of the 5 subarrays in myArray.

Comment: I would suggest adding some defense mechanisms in case a string is missing. Something like if ([subArray objectAtIndex:4]) {[myLabel5 setText: [subArray objectAtIndex:4]]}

Comment: cheers checked this out using the edit im still getting the first labels to load then a crash setting the seconds dont get why

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use C array :

```
id myArray[iMax][jMax];
subArray[i][j] = myArray[a][b];
```